# Set thumbnail for video in PHPhotoLibrary

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

I'm adding videos to the iOS photo library with `PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:`.

But the thumbnail shown in the library seems to be random.
Most of the time it is the start of the video, but sometimes something in the middle of the video.

Is there a way to save a custom thumbnail position or a custom thumbnail in the photo library?